# Pandas group by with multiple columns and max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some problems with `group by` with multiple columns and `max` value.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H

x   q   e   m   k   2   1   y
x   q   e   n   l   5   2   y
x   w   e   b   j   7   3   y
x   w   e   v   h   3   4   y
```

This query is correct and returning what I want.

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, MAX(F) FROM mytable group by A, B, C
```

Results

```
 x   q   e   n   l   5
 x   w   e   b   j   7
```

How it can be achieved in pandas?

I try this:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False)['F'].max()
```

And this translates to this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MAX(F) FROM mytable group by A, B, C
```

This also does not work

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False)['F','D','E'].max()
```

How can I return also column D, E as it in sql query?

Comment: Does `df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['F'].transform('max')` give you what you want?

Comment: Id suggest you posted a [mcve]

Comment: @RafaelC Thanks, added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
groups = ['A', 'B', 'C']
selects = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E','F']

df.groupby(groups, as_index=False).apply(lambda s: s.loc[s.F.idxmax(), selects]).reset_index(drop=True)

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   x   q   e   n   l   5
1   x   w   e   b   j   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False).agg({'D': 'first', 'E': 'last', 'F': 'max'})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but unfortunately it does not give the same as sql.

Comment: Well Pandas is not SQL so I'm not entirely sure what you're after.