# Pandas groupby two columns and get max value

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas groupby two columns and get max value

I have grouped data with multiindex

```
                        
    Model  VehicleType  VehicleType            
    100    sedan                278
           wagon                109
           coupe                  2
           convertible            1
    145    small                 19
    ...                         ...
    zafira sedan                 22
           small                 11
           suv                    7
           convertible            1
           coupe                  1
```

I need to get max value of count (right column) with corresponding model and VehicleType, like this:

```
                        
    Model  VehicleType  VehicleType            
    100    sedan                278
    145    small                 19
    ...                         ...
    zafira sedan                 22
```

Thanks for solutions!

Comment: Duplicate question. Probably you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789935/how-to-get-the-max-value-of-a-multiple-column-group-by-pandas,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457014/pandas-group-by-with-multiple-columns-and-max-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by maximum value and then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['VehicleType'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                    VehicleType
Model  VehicleType             
100    sedan                278
145    small                 19
zafira sedan                 22
```