# How to select best row of a grouped dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Lets say I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'class':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B'],
                            'name': ['max1', 'lisa1', 'max3', 'lisa2', 'lisa3'],
                             'gender': ['m', 'f','m','f','f'],
                            'grade':[2,3,1, 2,4]})
>>> print(df)
  class   name gender  grade
0     A   max1      m      2
1     A  lisa1      f      3
2     A   max3      m      1
3     B  lisa2      f      2
4     B  lisa3      f      4
```

I want to get the best student(s) of each class.(lower grade is better)

```
  class  grade   name gender
0     A      1   max3      m
1     B      2  lisa2      f
```

How would I achieve that with pandas?
Also if the best grade is not unique as in the above example how can I select the first occurrence of best/aggregate them to a list?

To clarify assume that lisa3 has a grade 2 instead of 4. Then the result I wish for would be:

- First occurrence: same as above
- aggregating into list:

```
  class  grade            name  gender
0     A      1          [max3]     [m]
1     B      2  [lisa2, lisa3]  [f, f]
```

Comment: For the first one, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457492/15032126). Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54471056/15032126), which is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the students by each class and for each class you can get the minimum using [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and then convert the rows that occurs more than once to list using [`pandas.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'class':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B'],
                        'name': ['max1', 'lisa1', 'max3', 'lisa2', 'lisa3'],
                         'gender': ['m', 'f','m','f','f'],
                        'grade':[2,3,1, 2,2]})

temp = df[df.grade == df.groupby(['class'])['grade'].transform('min')]
temp.groupby(['class', 'grade']).agg(pd.Series.tolist)
```

##### Output :

This gives you the expected output :

```
                       name  gender
class grade                        
A     1              [max3]     [m]
B     2      [lisa2, lisa3]  [f, f]
```

[`DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) will basically give you the minimal value for each group and returns a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values. In our case `min` for each group is returned corresponding to each index value.

So `df.groupby(['class'])['grade'].transform('min')` gives us

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
```

where `1` and `2` are the minimum values of their respective group, replicated for each row belonging to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['class','grade']).agg(list).groupby('class').head(1)
```

or

```
df.loc[df['grade'].eq(df.groupby('class')['grade'].transform('min'))].groupby(['class','grade']).agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                       name  gender
class grade                        
A     1              [max3]     [m]
B     2      [lisa2, lisa3]  [f, f]
```

Comment: `ValueError: No value provided for new tag's name` Also  could you provide explanation to answer as well

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby apply:

```
df.groupby("class", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x['grade'].eq(x['grade'].min())].\
                                          groupby(['class', 'grade'], as_index=False).\
                                          agg(list)).reset_index(drop=True)

  class  grade            name  gender
0     A      1          [max3]     [m]
1     B      2  [lisa2, lisa3]  [f, f]
```